# Adding new class member via LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query and because the variable that stores the result will be used in an "if" statement, I've had to initialize it before the query. This required making a class due to the different data types being stored in the list - however I'm having trouble making class members inside the LINQ query and I'm not sure why.

Class:

```
public class OtherProgramType
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PrgName { get; set; }
    public short? ProgramTypeID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }

}
```

Code:

```
List<OtherProgramType> otherPrograms;
otherPrograms = (from hm in db.HabitatManagement
                             join svy in db.Survey on hm.SurveyID equals svy.SurveyID
                             join iu in db.InventoryUsers on hm.UserID equals iu.UserID
                             join pt in db.ProgramType on hm.ProgramTypeID equals pt.ProgramTypeID
                             where pt.Program != "State Agency Public Land Programs"
                             && pt.Program != "State Agency Private Land Programs"
                             && svy.ReportingYear == (from svy in db.Survey
                                                      where svy.ReportingYear.HasValue
                                                      select svy.ReportingYear.Value).Max()
                             || pt.Program != "State Agency Public Land Programs"
                             && pt.Program != "State Agency Private Land Programs"
                             && svy.ReportingYear == (from svy in db.Survey
                                                      where svy.ReportingYear.HasValue
                                                      select svy.ReportingYear.Value).Max() - 1
                             select new
                             {
                                 iu.StateID,
                                 hm.ProgramTypeID,
                                 pt.Program
                             })
                             .Distinct()
                             .Select(x => new OtherProgramType { x.StateID, x.Program, x.ProgramTypeID, DisplayText = x.StateID.ToString() + ", " + x.Program.ToString() })
                             .OrderBy(x => x.StateID)
                             .ToList();
```

This is the line where I want the new class member to be made:
`.Select(x => new OtherProgramType { x.StateID, x.Program, x.ProgramTypeID, DisplayText = x.StateID.ToString() + ", " + x.Program.ToString() })`

The `x.StateID, x.Program, x.ProgramTypeID` get underlined in red squiggles and it says "Invalid initializer member declarator."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to state the field assignments, especially since the fields from `x` don't match the fields from your type `OtherProgramType`

```
.Select(x => new OtherProgramType 
{
    State = x.StateID, 
    PrgName = x.Program, 
    ProgramTypeID = x.ProgramTypeID, 
    DisplayText = x.StateID.ToString() + ", " + x.Program.ToString() 
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked well - so for the OrderBy statement, would I need to change it to .OrderBy(x => x.State)?

Comment: yes because after the Select you're working with a enumerable type of `OtherProgramType`

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the names of the properties you want to assign to:

```
.Select(x => new OtherProgramType {
     State = x.StateID,
     PrgName = x.Program,
     ProgramTypeID = x.ProgramTypeID, 
     DisplayText = x.StateID.ToString() + ", " + x.Program.ToString() 
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked well - so for the OrderBy statement, would I need to change it to `.OrderBy(x => x.State)`?

Answer (score 1):

Both the above answers are absolutely correct. Just to add:

If your class had a constructor taking all the parameters your code could have been:

```
public class OtherProgramType
{
  public OtherProgramType(string s, string pn, short? ptid, string dt)
  {
    this.State = s;
    this.PrgName = pn;
    this.ProgramTypeID = ptid;
    this.DisplayText = dt;
  }

  public string State { get; set; }
  public string PrgName { get; set; }
  public short? ProgramTypeID { get; set; }
  public string DisplayText { get; set; }
}
```

Now the appropriate line could be:

```
...
.Select(x => new OtherProgramType ( x.StateID, x.Program, x.ProgramTypeID, x.StateID.ToString() + ", " + x.Program.ToString() ))
...
```

Notice the `()` instead of `{}`.

Comment: Interesting - thank you for the info. Novice like me needs all the help they can get!! Is one more advantageous than the other?

Comment: As for the advantages, it maybe a matter of preference. There is one case that comes to mind where a constructor may be mandatory: when you have `readonly` properties or fields, they can only be assigned upon declaration (like `const`) or within a constructor. The difference from `const` is that the value does not need to be known at compile-time (and that `const` is by definition `static`, while you can have instance `readonly` or `static readonly` members).